# google app subscriptions by device and not by user

Tags: google-play, in-app-subscription

is there a way to bind a google play store subscription to the device and not to the user?

I know that some of my customers have 20 devices and more, all running with same google user account. And I don't want to have them paying for one user only, but using it on multiple devices.

If there's no way to define a by-device-subscription, I have to develop my own licensing server. Or are there any other options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this doesn't exist at the moment in Google Play.

Comment: Thanks. As we found no solution, we already started to develop our own licensing server.